# Is »Alterssuffkis« a correct German word or a misspelled one?

Tags: vocabulary

The article “[Generationsfrage Alkoholkonsum. Auf dem Weg zum Olymp.](http://taz.de/Generationsfrage-Alkoholkonsum/!5435944/)” from *taz.de* talks about alcohol consumption among older people. In the below paragraph the author describes his visit to the family doctor:

> Der Autor selbst, der im Jahr 2020 mit 52 Jahren die Reihen der **Alterssuffkis** aufstocken wird, erinnert sich noch gut an seinen letzten Hausarztbesuch, bei dem ihm, schon in der Tür stehend, noch angenehm moralfrei nachgerufen wurde: „Sie trinken gern mal einen – das sieht man an ihrem Blutbild.“ Darauf fiel mir nichts ein als ein bedröppeltes „Ja“, was wohl schon auf beginnende Demenz hinweist.

I could not find the word *Alterssuffkis* or *Suffkis* in any of the dictionaries I use. From the context, *Alterssuffkis* seems to meen *old drinker*. Perhaps, *Suffkis* is derived from *der Suff*, meaning *boozing*.

So, is *Alterssuffkis* a correct German word or a misspelled one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Suffki" is in fact derived from the noun "Suff" or the verb "saufen", using a suffix to construct a new noun, meaning "boozer".  The only parallel construction coming to my mind is "Knacki" (Con, Jailbird) derived from "verknacken" / "knacken". But there, the root already contains a "k", so the suffix is simply "i"; with "Suffki", i can't explain why there's a "k" between root and suffix. Maybe it should be a shortcut for "Suffkopp" or something like that... The derivation is similar to "Ossi" / "Wessi", deriving from "Ostdeutscher" / "Westdeutscher".

It seems to be specific for the Berlin dialect; at least, the "taz" used it in 1989 already, as [cited by the Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-13493812.html), for example. You'll find it rarely [in books, too](https://books.google.de/books?id=JyTSAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&dq=suffki&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib4M_ml_DVAhUBCBoKHTu0BNwQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=suffki&f=false). So, you may say it's correct german, but to me, it's clearly colloquial language.

Comment: Ich nehme an, dass die Endung scherzhaft dem Russischen oder ähnlichem nachempfunden ist.